# How to set conditional service rates in simmer package in R for discrete event simulation?

Tags: r, queue, simulation

I am trying to model failure and repair of 2 machines with 1 resource (repairman) available which I can do as follows:

```
reset(env.ex3)
env.ex3 <- simmer("FailureRepair ex3")

lambda1 <- 0.01 # Failure rate
lambda2 <- 0.02
mu1 <- 0.2 # Repair rate
mu2 <- 0.4

traj <- trajectory() %>%
  seize("Repairman") %>%
  timeout(function() rexp(1, mu1)) %>%
  release("Repairman")

env.ex3 %>%
  add_resource("Repairman", queue_size = Inf) %>%
  add_generator("failureOne", traj, function() rexp(1, lambda1)) %>%
  add_generator("failureTwo", traj, function() rexp(1, lambda2)) %>%
  run(until = 1000000)

env.ex3 %>% get_mon_arrivals(per_resource = T)
```

Notice that I used only one trajectory for resource with `mu1`. I would like to extend this model so that "failureOne" and "failureTwo" have different service rates (`mu1` and `mu2`, respectively) from the same resource. So the underlying assumption is, if a resource is occupied in servicing a failure, other failure has to wait until the resource becomes available.

If I use two separate trajectory, as per my understanding, it would mean there are two separate resources for repairing and if the failure times of two machines overlap then they will be repaired simultaneously, which I do not want to model.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

You defined one unit of "repairman", and you can use that resource from as many trajectories as you like: if one gets the resource, the others wait. Use two trajectories:

```
traj1 <- trajectory() %>%
  seize("Repairman") %>%
  timeout(function() rexp(1, mu1)) %>%
  release("Repairman")

traj2 <- trajectory() %>%
  seize("Repairman") %>%
  timeout(function() rexp(1, mu2)) %>%
  release("Repairman")

env.fr2 %>%
  add_resource("Repairman", queue_size = Inf) %>%
  add_generator("M1.failure", traj1, M1.running) %>%
  add_generator("M2.failure", traj2, M2.running) %>%
  run(100000)
```

Comment: I added your suggestion in my question. Is this what you meant? As per my understanding, it means I have two independent repairman who are in charge of the two types of failure arrival separately. So if they are both failed in overlapping time they will be simultaneously repaired. Isn't it so? but I want both failure arrival to go to the same repairman but getting repair done with different repair rate given the type of failures.  Can you please provide feedback?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. I meant two trajectories calling the "Repairman" you already had, not "Repairman1" and "Repairman2".

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused with how does that solve the problem assigning two repair rates mu1 and mu2 to the arrivals failureOne and failureTwo respectively?

Comment: One trajectory calls "repairmain" with "mu1"; the other calls also "repairman" with "mu2".

Comment: Comment updated with my suggestion. Please, remove your update because that's not what I suggested.

Comment: I have a general question which is about add_generator(). My understanding is that, this function keeps generating arrivals even when the resource is occupied and put them into a queue. Is it possible that, when a resource is occupied, it doesn't generate anymore arrivals until the resource is free?

Comment: I suggest you to post these questions in the mailing list. There's a link in the homepage r-simmer.org.